# How to make a Swift Enum with Associated values conform to Codable?

Tags: swift, enums, codable

I would use enum in a struct with codable protocol. But I do not know, hogy to make one `init` for enum. Compiler raise error if I do not have an `init`.

The goal here is the the `value` parameter in the `UpdateIn` type can be two thing, either a string or a `FormFiled` struct.

Do you know maybe how to make this init?

```
struct UpdateIn: Content {
    var keyPath: [String]
    var value: Value
    var operation: String
}
```

---

```
enum Value: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        <#code#>
    }
    
  case str(String)
  case formField(FormField)
}
```

---

```
struct FormField: Content {
    var name: String
    var type: String
    var options: [String: FormFieldOption]?
    var selectedOption: String?
    var visibleIfIndIsVisible: Int?
    var ind: Int
    var mandatory: Bool // TODO: isMandatory
    var dateCreatedAt: Date?
    var selectItemOtherArbitraryValueEnable: Bool?
    var regex: String?
    var hasImage: Bool?
    var defaultFormFieldOptionId: String?
}
```

---

Based on answer I try to extract the value and assign to a specific variable, but it is refused, do you know why?

```swift
let formField: FormField = params.value
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'Value' to specified type 'FormField'

Comment: This depends on what your data looks like. Ultimately you just end up assigning to self, either `self = .string(someStringValue)`, `self = .formField(someFormField)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to switch your enumeration associated values:

```
enum Value: Codable {
    case str(String)
    case formField(FormField)
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case str, formField
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        switch self {
        case let .str(string):
            try container.encode(string, forKey: .str)
        case let .formField(field):
            try container.encode(field, forKey: .formField)
        }
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        switch container.allKeys.first {
        case .str:
            self = try .str(container.decode(String.self, forKey: .str))
        case .formField:
            self = try .formField(container.decode(FormField.self, forKey: .formField))
        default:
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(
                .init(
                    codingPath: container.codingPath,
                    debugDescription: "invalid data"
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, how can I get the value, refer to value? I tried: `value.formField` but compiler says: `Cannot assign value of type '(FormField) -> Value' to subscript of type 'FormField'`

Comment: @János not sure where you are getting this error. Feel free to edit your post and show what you tried and the issues you are facing. Note that you didn't post `FormFieldOption` declaration. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You need to switch your value it can be a string or a FormField. Check the encoding switch syntax

Comment: switch  params.value {
        case let .str(string):
            print(string)
        case let .formField(field):
            print(field)
        }

Comment: Would you check this here? Got stuck. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68509201/how-to-use-enum-with-assotiate-values-together-with-codable-protocol

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 5.5+

Swift 5.5 allows enums with associated values to automatically conform to `Codable` (if their associated values are `Codable`):

```swift
enum Animal: Codable {
   case dog(breed: String)
   case cat(declawed: Bool)
}

let dog = Animal.dog(breed: "Husky")
let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(dog)
let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
print(string)
```

Result:

```json
{"dog":{"breed":"Husky"}}
```

---

### Swift <5.5

You'll have to manually implement `encode(to:)` and `init(from:)`, just like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68492528/15959847).