# How to use enum with assotiated values together with codable protocol?

Tags: json, swift, enums, codable

I would decode the following JSON, but it fails.

```json
{
    "keyPath": [
        "791186780675587"
    ],
    "value": {
        "name": "fff"
    },
    "operation": "setValue"
}
```

Decoder should be able to decode the following too:

```json
{
    "keyPath": [
        "791186780675587"
    ],
    "value": "some_string",
    "operation": "setValue"
}
```

Difference is in `value` field.

The root element has the type `UpdateIn`

```swift
struct UpdateIn: Content {
    var keyPath: [String]
    var value: Value
    var operation: String
}
```

`value` inside is declared as `enum`

But something wring how `enum` is declared, but I do not see what.

```swift
enum Value: Codable {
    case str(String)
    case formField(FormField)
    case passType(PassType)
    case event(Event)
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case str, formField, passType, event
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        switch self {
        case let .str(string):
            try container.encode(string, forKey: .str)
        case let .formField(field):
            try container.encode(field, forKey: .formField)
        case let .passType(field):
            try container.encode(field, forKey: .passType)
        case let .event(field):
            try container.encode(field, forKey: .event)
        }
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        switch container.allKeys.first {
        case .str:
            self = try .str(container.decode(String.self, forKey: .str))
        case .formField:
            self = try .formField(container.decode(FormField.self, forKey: .formField))
        case .passType:
            self = try .passType(container.decode(PassType.self, forKey: .passType))
        case .event:
            self = try .event(container.decode(Event.self, forKey: .event))
        default:
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(
                .init(
                    codingPath: container.codingPath,
                    debugDescription: "invalid data"
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Basically `value` field could be 4 different type, simple string, or Event, or the two other. (PassType, FormField)

```swift
case str(String)
case formField(FormField)
case passType(PassType)
case event(Event)
```

Running decode will raise this error:

> invalid data for key value

Because in `switch` the `default` case get called, because `container.allKeys` has 0 item, and so `switch container.allKeys.first` will jump to `default`.

So what is wrong with the `Value` declaration?

Ahh yes, and this is how `Event` struct look like:

```swift
struct Event: Content {
    var name: String
}
```

Comment: Hey did you get your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you need a custom decoder for the `Value`, **NOT** for the `UpdateIn`!

Assuming `Event` is a `decodable`. you first try to decode to the first type (string in your case) and then move to the next and next.

```
enum Value {
    case string(String)
    case event(Event)
}

extension Value: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let string = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(string)
        } else {
            try self = .event(container.decode(Event.self))
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Full sample

```
let j1 = """
{
    "keyPath": [
        "791186780675587"
    ],
    "value": {
        "name": "fff"
    },
    "operation": "setValue"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let j2 = """

{
    "keyPath": [
        "791186780675587"
    ],
    "value": "simpleStrig",
    "operation": "setValue"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct UpdateIn: Decodable {
    var keyPath: [String]
    var value: Value
    var operation: String
}

enum Value {
    case string(String)
    case event(Event)
}

struct Event: Codable {
    var name: String
}

extension Value: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let string = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(string)
        } else {
            try self = .event(container.decode(Event.self))
        }
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
print(try! decoder.decode(UpdateIn.self, from: j1).value)
print(try! decoder.decode(UpdateIn.self, from: j2).value)
```